# How to use table valued function as part of select statement in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have a select statement which returns a table. I want to select a table valued function as a part of that select statement, which also returns a table.. How to do that.

This is my select code which returns a table

```
SELECT 
    dbo.TC_User.JobTitle, dbo.TC_User.UserID, 
    dbo.TC_User.LocalID, dbo.TC_User.NokiaID, dbo.TC_User.NameCN,
    dbo.TC_User.职阶 as EmployeeGroup, 
    dbo.TC_User2.LockDateID, dbo.TC_User.StartDate, 
    dbo.TC_User.EndDate, dbo.TC_User.StartDateN, 
    dbo.TC_User.聘用前工号, dbo.TC_User.NoCheckFlag, 
    dbo.GetGroupPath2('465') AS Path  
FROM 
    dbo.TC_User 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.TC_User2 ON dbo.TC_User.UserID = dbo.TC_User2.UserID 
WHERE 
    (dbo.TC_User.UserID IN (SELECT UserID 
                            FROM dbo.TC_User 
                            WHERE (GroupID IN (SELECT GroupID 
                                               FROM dbo.VSGetSubGroupTab(10, 1) AS VSGetSubGroupTab))))
```

This is what I want

```
SELECT 
    dbo.TC_User.JobTitle, dbo.TC_User.UserID,
    dbo.GetGroupPath2Clone('465') as grouppath,
    dbo.TC_User.LocalID, dbo.TC_User.NokiaID, dbo.TC_User.NameCN, 
    dbo.TC_User.职阶 as EmployeeGroup, 
    dbo.TC_User2.LockDateID, dbo.TC_User.StartDate, 
    dbo.TC_User.EndDate, dbo.TC_User.StartDateN, 
    dbo.TC_User.聘用前工号, dbo.TC_User.NoCheckFlag, 
    dbo.GetGroupPath2('465') AS Path  
FROM 
    dbo.TC_User 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.TC_User2 ON dbo.TC_User.UserID = dbo.TC_User2.UserID 
WHERE 
    (dbo.TC_User.UserID IN (SELECT UserID 
                            FROM dbo.TC_User 
                            WHERE (GroupID IN (SELECT GroupID 
                                               FROM dbo.VSGetSubGroupTab(10, 1) AS VSGetSubGroupTab))))
```

`dbo.GetGroupPath2Clone('465')` as grouppath, is the table valued function which I want to call. How to do that?

Comment: Looks like you are already using other table valued function `dbo.VSGetSubGroupTab(10, 1) `. Do it the same way, use `dbo.GetGroupPath2Clone('465')` in FROM / JOIN clause and its columns in SELECT / WHERE / ON.

Comment: Besides the answers you've got already, you might read about `OUTER APPLY` and `CROSS APPLY`

Comment: @Serg Hi, that dbo.VSGetSubGroupTab(10, 1) is used inside a where clause to check if the group id passed exists or not. But fordbo.GetGroupPath2Clone('465') I want to add those columns returned by it to the main table. how to do that? Thanks

Comment: Most probaly you should CROSS /OUTER/ INNER JOIN it.

Answer (score 0):

the dbo.GetGroupPath2 looks like a scalar function. However, if it is a table function then you need to place it in the join list.

```
SELECT 
dbo.TC_User.JobTitle, dbo.TC_User.UserID, 
dbo.TC_User.LocalID, dbo.TC_User.NokiaID, dbo.TC_User.NameCN,
dbo.TC_User.职阶 as EmployeeGroup, 
dbo.TC_User2.LockDateID, dbo.TC_User.StartDate, 
dbo.TC_User.EndDate, dbo.TC_User.StartDateN, 
dbo.TC_User.聘用前工号, dbo.TC_User.NoCheckFlag, 
 tf.yourfield1, tf.yourfield2, ...etc. 
FROM 
dbo.TC_User 
join dbo.GetGroupPath2('465') AS tf on tf.yourkey=somekeys
INNER JOIN 
dbo.TC_User2 ON dbo.TC_User.UserID = dbo.TC_User2.UserID 
WHERE 
(dbo.TC_User.UserID IN (SELECT UserID 
                        FROM dbo.TC_User 
                        WHERE (GroupID IN (SELECT GroupID 
                                           FROM dbo.VSGetSubGroupTab(10, 1) AS VSGetSubGroupTab))))
```

to create the table function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].GetGroupPath2 
(
    @Parm varchar(10)
)
Returns Table 
As
Return (
    Select yourfield1, yourfield2
   From   yourTable
   where [yourKey] = @Parm
)
```